# Does Container.getComponents() return references to the original components?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I'm using Container.getComponents() to get an array of Components stored inside the Container. I'm then modifying one of these Components (which happens to be a JLabel), but the changes are not showing on the GUI.

So I'm thinking maybe the method creates new instances of each Component which prevents me from making changes to the original component?

Here's my code:

```
Component[] components = source.getComponents();
if(components.length >= 2) {
    if(components[1] instanceof JLabel) {
        JLabel htmlArea = (JLabel) components[1];
        htmlArea.setText("<html>new changes here</html>");
        htmlArea.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want my bandwidth back - you can keep your pictures of politicians!

Comment: No, it returns references to the contained objects. Something outside the snipit of code you provided is wrong. (Or, you need to revalidate the container - it's been a while since I've done swing, I don't remember how changes propagate)

Comment: Okay Brian thanks - if you're sure it returns references. My code's massive so I guess I'll just try to find the mistake myself, rather than you guessing.. I am also revalidating the container, I just missed that bit of the code when I copied it. I'm repainting too, just in case!

Comment: There is no need to revalidate() or repaint() the component or the container. Swing does that automatically, when a property, like setText() is changed.

Comment: I'm showing this JLabel inside a JTabbedPane and if I change the tab and then change it back it shows the changes. But yes camickr, it makes no difference whether or not I add revalidate() or repaint(). Maybe I need to revalidate parent components?

Comment: Are you certain `components[1]` is a JLabel? That's an awfully magic number you have there.

Comment: @Brian, yes definitely because I added a println there and it printed. And as I said above, it is actually changing the JLabel but just not showing the changes. This is a different question now though, so I'll ask again later if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either another problem outside of the code, or you are doing this from the wrong thread.

Any changes on Swing components should be done in the event dispatch thread. Often is it most easy to surround the changing code with `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` (or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, this is the same).

And make sure your component is actually visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to revalidate() or repaint() anything (unless you are doing something really strange)!

Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem???

It works fine for me:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TabbedPaneLabel extends JFrame
{
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

    public TabbedPaneLabel()
    {
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        add(tabbedPane);

        tabbedPane.addTab("First", createPanel("<html>label with text</html>"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Second", createPanel("another label"));

        JButton remove = new JButton("Change Label on first tab");
        add(remove, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        remove.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Component[] components = tabbedPane.getComponents();
                JPanel panel = (JPanel)components[0];
                JLabel label = (JLabel)panel.getComponent(0);
                String date = new Date().toString();
                label.setText("<html>" + date + "</html>");
            }
        });
    }

    private JPanel createPanel(String text)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add( new JLabel(text) );
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TabbedPaneLabel frame = new TabbedPaneLabel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```